# Background Layout Listeners Being Called through Foreground Listener

Tags: java, android, listener, mapbox

I have a persistent BottomSheet covering a MapView. The MapView has a longClickListener. If I long click on the BottomSheet the MapViews longClickerListener will be called even though I am not pressing it. How do I prevent listeners from the MapView from being called when I perform actions on the BottomSheet?

Another example is if you double tap on the BottomSheet, the map will zoom in.

[image: example]

Comment: The view used for the Bottom Sheet view should have `clickable="true"` `focusable="true"` and `focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Comment: Also make sure you're returning `true` on the bottom sheet click listeners (to prevent click propagation)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! @ElliotM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view used for the Bottom Sheet view should have `clickable="true"` `focusable="true"` and `focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Also make sure you're returning `true` on the bottom sheet click listeners (to prevent click propagation)